# Why all but 1 Route is working with Backbone Router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router

In the script below are various routes and view and routes events built with Backbone.js
Why is it, that all of the routes work as I expect except the last one 'products'.

I originally had it as a very different function but realized it wasn't firing off, but not even as a duplicate of the other views and routes it still wont work.

Anyone have an idea why?
Thanks you!

I am also very new to Backbone.
Rich

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Undie Couture by Lauren Copeland</title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/museosans_500_macroman/stylesheet.css" />
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/site/front-styles.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <header>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div id="logo"></div>
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/#/products/">shop</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/#/contact">contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/#/about">about</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/#/wholesale">wholesale</a></li>
                                </nav>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="page" id="first" style="display:none;"></div>
                        <div class="page"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        <script type="text/template" id="title-temp">
            <%= title %>
        </script>
        <script type="text/template" id="logo-temp">
            <a href="/#/home" id="logo"><img src="/assets/img/logo-strip.png" /></a>
        </script>
        <script type="text/template" id="home-temp">
            <%= title %>
        </script>
        <script type="text/template" id="page-temp">
            <h1><%= page.pluck('title') %></h1>
            <div id="body">
               <%= page.pluck('body') %>
            </div>
        </script>
        <script type="text/template" id="product-temp">
            <h1><%= page.pluck('name') %></h1>
            <div id="body">
                <%= page.pluck('description') %>
            </div>
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery.js">    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/libs/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/libs/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>


<script type = "text/javascript">

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "home": "home",
        "about": "about",
        "contact": "contact",
        "wholesale": "wholesale",
        "products": "products"
    }
});
var Page = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Page model loaded');
    },
    defaults: {
        "id": "",
        "title": "",
        "body": "",
        "slug": ""
    },
    urlRoot: '/backbone/page'
});

var Pages = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('pages collection loaded');
    },
    url: '/backbone/page'
});


var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: $('#standard').html(),
    el: '.page:first',
    change: function() {
        $('.page').fadeOut('slow');
    },
    render: function() {
        logo = $('#logo-temp').html();
        $('#logo').html(logo);
        $('.content').attr('id', 'home');
        var that = this;
        that.change();
        compiled = _.template($('#home-temp').html(), {
            title: ''
        });
        that.$el.html(compiled);
    }
});

var AboutView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: $('#standard').html(),
    el: '.page:first',
    change: function() {},
    render: function() {
        console.log('render')
        var that = this;
        logo = $('#logo-temp').html();
        $('#logo').html(logo);
        $('.content').attr('id', 'about');
        aboutPage = new Pages();
        aboutPage.fetch({
            data: {
                id: 3
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#first').fadeOut({
                    duration: 400,
                    complete: function() {
                        console.log(aboutPage.models)
                        compiled = _.template($('#page-temp').html(), {
                            page: aboutPage
                        });
                        that.$el.html(compiled).delay(300).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: $('#standard').html(),
    el: '.page:first',
    change: function() {
        $('.page').fadeOut();
    },
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        logo = $('#logo-temp').html();
        $('#logo').html(logo);
        $('.content').attr('id', 'contact');
        contactPage = new Pages();
        contactPage.fetch({
            data: {
                id: 2
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#first').fadeOut({
                    duration: 400,
                    complete: function() {
                        console.log(contactPage.models)
                        compiled = _.template($('#page-temp').html(), {
                            page: contactPage
                        });
                        that.$el.html(compiled).delay(300).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

var WholesaleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: $('#standard').html(),
    el: '.page:first',
    change: function() {},
    render: function() {
        console.log('render')
        var that = this;
        logo = $('#logo-temp').html();
        $('#logo').html(logo);
        $('.content').attr('id', 'about');
        wholePage = new Pages();
        wholePage.fetch({
            data: {
                id: 4
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#first').fadeOut({
                    duration: 400,
                    complete: function() {
                        console.log(wholePage.models)
                        compiled = _.template($('#page-temp').html(), {
                            page: wholePage
                        });
                        that.$el.html(compiled).delay(300).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: $('#standard').html(),
    el: '.page:first',
    change: function() {},
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        logo = $('#logo-temp').html();
        $('#logo').html(logo);
        $('.content').attr('id', 'about');
        wholePage = new Pages();
        wholePage.fetch({
            data: {
                id: 4
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#first').fadeOut({
                    duration: 400,
                    complete: function() {
                        console.log(wholePage.models)
                        compiled = _.template($('#page-temp').html(), {
                            page: wholePage
                        });
                        that.$el.html(compiled).delay(300).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

var router = new Router();

var page_model = new Page();

var page_col = new Pages();

var home = new HomeView();

var about = new AboutView();

var contact = new ContactView();

var wholesale = new WholesaleView();

var products = new ProductView();

router.on('route:home', function() {
    home.render();
});

router.on('route:about', function() {
    about.render();
});

router.on('route:contact', function() {
    contact.render();
});

router.on('route:wholesale', function() {
    wholesale.render();
});

router.on('route:products', function() {
    products.render();
});


Backbone.history.start(); 
</script>
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `products.render();` does it get hit?  Do you get any errors logged in console?

Comment: Can you include the HTML or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Updated to include HTML. No errors are generated when I run this on my server.

Comment: what happens if you try and render products twice and put a breakpoint after the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anchor tag for shops has a trailing /

```
<a href="/#/products/">
```

Should be

```
<a href="/#/products">
```

Removing that made the route work for me.

Comment: This was the reason. Odd, I thought I had tried this too. Thanks Fiskers!